# Writing a CPU bound script to gauge rough CPU performance

Tags: python, performance, cpu

I have wrote a script and running it on different machines. Script looks like below

```
def f(n):
    x = None
    while n:
        x = simple_math(n)
        n -= 1
    return x

start = now()
f(BIGNUM)    
print now() - start
```

At the end of the script it print how much time does it take to finish. Is this good enough to  compare different machine for practical CPU speed for **simple Python scripts**?

By simple I mean it does not use multiprocessing module or any other technique to take advantage of multi-core machines.

This question is *not* about

- making python programs run faster
- multiprocessing module
- GIL, I/O efficiency etc.
- non cPython programs

Just that I want make sure if my approach to understand CPU performance among machines is fairly correct.

Comment: Given a sufficiently smart Python (like Jython) the class to _f_ might be optimized away as there does not seem to be a side effect. I would expect this code to be optimized away by the JIT if it were Java code.

Comment: @extraneon: Well, optimizing it away as side-effect free would (1) require very extensive analysis in the general case and (2) not save much in most real code but (3) break this kind of benchmark. So I don't think most JITs would try to remove it. I don't think PyPy does this as they use this kind of benchmark on a regular basis (see e.g. http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2011/01/loop-invariant-code-motion.html) and I'd be surprised if Jython was smarter than PyPy's JIT.

Comment: @anijhaw Thanks for pystone suggestion, will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a rough idea by using these type of methods. But that will not be exact measurement. The execution time of the script will depend on many other things other than CPU speed, like OS and interpreter version used, current system load, memory speed etc. etc. My suggestion is not to depend on this.

EDIT: Just a note. When it comes to performance, many people think only about CPU speed, but actually performance can be hampered by almost everything on the system. For example you have a high speed CPU but low RAM (both in size and speed), then you will get no performance boost up for the CPU.

Comment: I know other factors are important but I am just interested in getting rough idea CPU speed. Assumption is rest of the environment is same.

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with all of the countless existing benchmarks? The more sophisticated ones are propably a bit more robust. The major problems of your naive approach I - and I'm not an expert on this topic, mind you - can spot are:

- Modern CPUs are highly complex and employ very clever optimizations. The speed of a purely CPU-bound can vary widely depending on how often the cache can help, how often the program causes pipeline stalls, how often branch prediction is correct, and propably many many more (these were just off the top of my head). Although many of these shouldn't make a difference when you use the same build of the same executable running the same script doing the same [pure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) calculations, they can matter - to a degree none of us can predict - once you change any of these paramteres (e.g. using a different build because of a different OS or architecture).
- Multi-threading OSs will never let a program occupy the CPU exclusively. There will always be some other program running at the same time stealing time, and you can't really know how much of the x seconds were spent running your program and how many were spent on other programs. At the very least, you should run a program many times and take the minimum time as the time it takes with relatively little inference from other programs. And even then, you need to have about the same system load in both benchmarks to make the numbers somewhat meaningful.
- At least CPython won't multi-thread, so you only get the speed of *one* core.

But since your requirements seem to be "very rough estimate of CPU speed only, in full awareness that these numbers can't be used for anything except putting CPU speed into orders of magnitude, must be taken with a grain of salt even then and don't tell anything about the actual performance of any real applications", it might be okay - just don't consider it anywhere close to accurate. Still, why not use a hardened benchmark suite that already put some effort into mitigating (not removing - nobody can do that) these problems?

Also note that the `timeit` stdlib module is both easier to use than manually wielding the stopwatch and tries (not too hard, but it's a start) to fix the second point by the method I mentioned.

Comment: Nice explanation, much more robust than mine.

Comment: Agreed about timeit. I am looking for simple CPU benchmarking of machine (not 100% scientific not 100% accurate) for _simple Python scripts_ keeping in mind Python language's limitations.

Answer (score 1):

In essence: No.

Benchmarking is a very difficult problem which usually is not worth solving yourself.  It all depends on why you care.  Your method will surely give a very rough estimate on if System A is better than System B, but really only when the outcome is vastly different.

What you're trying to do is determine how Real World Application X will perform on different computers.  Very rarely is a real world application approximated by a loop of simple math.  Even when it is (scientific computing mostly) you're better off measuring times on the actual program.

Real world applications are usually non-linear, and difficult to measure and simulate.  Its really one of those problems which has been solved by someone else much better than you could reasonably solve yourself.

If you want a very rough estimate of performance, sure do it your way.  Just don't put too much faith in the results because they will be far from what you might call "scientific"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention correctly (and you could clarify it a bit - what is it exactly that you are trying to measure or estimate, processor speed, code speed, something else and for what purpose, but if I understand you then) why not check how is it done in [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html)

Comment: I am trying to get a rough idea of CPU efficiency of machines for _Simple Python scripts_. Say rest of the factors like memory, I/O, interpreter, OS are exactly same. 

Yes I can/will use eventually timeit but I am just checking my approach with others.

Comment: What I meant was to take a look at http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/timeit.py to see all considerations made.